# Wordpress Sage Singleton Service in blade template

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-blade

I'm starting to develop a Wordpress theme with DDEV + Bedrock + Sage.

I have some issues using singleton classes in my blade templates.

This is my code so far to wire things together:

Singleton Service which should be used anywhere in the Project's Logic

```
final class TestService
{
public static string $name = "TestService";

private static ?TestService $instance = null;

public static function getInstance(): TestService
{
    if (self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

private function __construct()
{
}

private function __clone()
{
}

public function __wakeup()
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot unserialize singleton");
}
public function testMethod()
{
   return true;
}
}
```

Service provider to make the service available

```
<?php
 namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
  use App\Services\TestService;

 class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // Register services in ServiceProviderOne
    $this->app->singleton("TestService", function () {
        return TestService::getInstance();
    });
}

/**
 * Bootstrap services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}
}
```

Blade page template which should use the service for some logic and display content accordingly

```
@php
$testService = app("TestService");
$isTest = $testService->testMethod();
@endphp
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
  @while(have_posts()) @php(the_post())
    @includeFirst(['partials.content-page', 'partials.content'])
  @endwhile
@endsection
```

But the result now is the following error

Target class [TestService] does not exist. (View: /var/www/html/web/app/themes/theme/resources/views/test-page.blade.php)

Is my setup with the singleton and provider wrong? Did I miss some config?